How can I get VLOOKUP to return a response that is in one of two adjacent columns?
I have the following working formula in my header row and that returns an array of "Project Team Owner" values from my Form Responses sheet based on a matching Unique ID:
={"Project Team Owner"; 
   INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A,'Form Responses'!A2:U,COLUMN('Form Responses'!G2:G),0)))}

The problem I'm having is that the "Project Team Owner" will be in one of (not both) Form Responses Column G or Column H.
How can I modify my formula so it will return the result from Column H if it isn't found in Column G?
Sample Data
Link to example Google spreadsheet
Form Responses




A
B - F
G
H




1
Unique ID

Value 1
Value 2


2
PID-1

TCP



3
PID-2


Computing Services



Desired Result (Formula in B1)




A
B




1
Unique ID
Project Team Owner


2
PID-1
TCP


3
PID-2
Computing Services




BYROW
You can use VLOOKUP to return a two-column array then use JOIN in BYROW to combine them into one.
={"Project Team Owner"; 
  BYROW(
    INDEX(
      IFNA(
        VLOOKUP(A2:A, 'Form Responses'!A2:F, {7,8},))),
    LAMBDA(r, JOIN(,r)))}

BYROW  IFNA  INDEX  JOIN  LAMBDA  VLOOKUP
LET
Create an array inside the VLOOKUP by combining the range with a merged column made from columns G and H
={"Project Team Owner";
  LET(
    rng,'Form Responses'!A2:F,  
    INDEX(
      IFNA(
        VLOOKUP(A2:A, {rng, INDEX(rng,,7) & INDEX(rng,,8)}, 9,))))} 

IFNA  INDEX  LET  VLOOKUP
